# Error in passing form input to React components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am completely new to React and going through the Facebook documentation quite frequently for various small problems. One I am currently stuck with and cannot find an answer for is this - I have a form whose inputs I am trying to pass to a React component. The form is partially shown below:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label>Height</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="height">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label>Weight</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="weight">
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div id="container"></div>
```

My call to the React component is given next:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import {ProfileList} from './react/components/list.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <ProfileList age={document.getElementById('age').value} height={document.getElementById('height').value} weight={document.getElementById('weight').value} ,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Finally, my component (partially):

```
export class ProfileList extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        ProfileList.propTypes = {
            age: React.PropTypes.number,
            height: React.PropTypes.number,
            weight: React.PropTypes.number
        };
        return (
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

I get an `Unexpected token`  while parsing the jsx file (which has the ProfileList component code). Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The propTypes belong to the class component like this:

```
class ProfileList { ... }
ProfileList.propTypes = { ... }
export ProfileList;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have two root nodes in your component. Wrap it in 'div' element